# Modernizr .load() for jquerymobile lag issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, modernizr

I am attempting to use modernizr.js to use a media query "mq()" and load ".load()" to have a jquerymobile version of a website fire on load based on the media query result, i am having issue with the .load() function

testing in safari, something is causing a large lag, having the resources load after all the content
after pointing to the modernizr.js, i have tried

```
  <script type="text/javascript" >
   Modernizr.load('js/jqm-b2.js'); 
   </script>
```

and have tried this

```
 Modernizr.load([
 {
  test : Modernizr.mq('only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)'),
 yep : ['js/jqm-b2.js'],
 nope : ''
     }
    }
 ]);
```

both give the same result, page displays content then loads the scripts after the fact, so that the page jumps from html to suddenly jquerymobile enhanced

I used the production modernizr download, and selected media queries and load.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up solving like this, made sure it loaded either/or rather than just or

```
Modernizr.load([

{
test : Modernizr.mq('only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width:   768px)'),

yep : ['js/jqm-b2.js'],
nope : ['js/desktop.js'],
...
```